# Unit test for coverage checking (java, junit)

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I want to have a unit test that checks if all methods defined in a class/interface are covered with unit tests.

There is an interface and a number of classes that implement that interface.
Since the classes are related, and some methods are critical for performance, there is some amount of copied/pasted/modified code.
I want to make sure that unit tests for each class (that implements that interface) cover:

1. all methods declared in the interface
2. all methods declared in the class

This *is* meaningful because such tests discover:

1. code that was not modified after copying/pasting
2. methods inherited from the base class that must be redefined

Currently I use the following tool (in the coding convention that I use all testing classes and methods must end with "Test"):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

public class TestCoverage {
    public static void check(Class appClass, Class testingClass) {
        assertTrue("testingClass must end with \"Test\"", testingClass.getSimpleName().endsWith("Test"));
        var appMethodNamesToTest =
                Arrays.stream(appClass.getDeclaredMethods())
                        // .filter(m -> !Modifier.isStatic(m.getModifiers()))
                        .map(Method::getName)
                        .filter(s -> !s.contains("$")) // filter out $jacocoInit
                        .map(s -> s + "Test")
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
        var testingMethodNames =
                Arrays.stream(testingClass.getDeclaredMethods())
                        .map(Method::getName)
                        .filter(s -> s.endsWith("Test"))
                        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        var missingMethods = appMethodNamesToTest.stream()
                .filter(methodName -> !testingMethodNames.contains(methodName))
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
        if (!missingMethods.isEmpty()) {
            fail("missing test methods in " + testingClass.getSimpleName() + ": " + missingMethods);
        }
    }
}
```

which is used as:

```
public class FooTest {

    // unit tests go here

    @Test
    public void coverageTest() {
        TestCoverage.check(Baar.class, getClass()); // interface
        TestCoverage.check(Foo.class, getClass());  // implementing class
    }
}
```

What is really good is that I get an early warning about methods not covered by the tests.

Strictly speaking, `coverageTest()` is not a unit test.

In the above code, `getClass()` returns `FooTest.class`, but unlike `FooTest.class`, it need not be modified when you copy/paste `coverageTest()`. In theory, it should be possible to extract the calling class from an exception stack trace, but this is complex.

**EDIT {**

The problem that I want to solve is a bit different from what the coverage tools usually do. I am interested in *per-interface test coverage,* not *per-method test coverage.* With the existing coverage tools, in the following example there is no way to force the developer to define `C.c()`:

```
interface I { void a(); void b(); default void c() {...} }
class A { // defines a() and b(); the default c() is correct
}
class B { // defines a() and b(); the default c() is correct
}
class C { // defines a() and b(); the default c() is NOT correct
}
```

If `I.c()` is covered by at least some test, it will be green, and `C.c()` does not exist and therefore cannot be marked red.

`TestCoverage.check()` does make the developer write tests for `A.c()`, `B.c()` and `C.c()` and hopefully mention that `c()` must be defined in `C`.
On the other hand, classes `A` and `B` share the common implementation `I.c()`, but the test for `c()` has to be copied.

In other words, what I want is *make sure all interface methods are covered by tests in each implementing class.*

**}**

Since it is very unlikely that I "invented a wheel",

**Question:**
Have such checks been already implemented in the existing testing frameworks?

Comment: Doesn't it make more sense to have a test coverage tool in the build process? Those also provide a lot more detail like line and branch coverage.

Comment: @daniu You see, "covered by at least some unit test" and "covered by the class-specific unit test" are two different things. I want all interface methods to be covered in the tests for each class implementing that interface.

Comment: This might be a good opportunity to use [ArchUnit](https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit) for such validations? I'm not entirely sure whether it supports it (interface level validation) but it worth looking into it.

Comment: Disregard the chronology, I just found out that for Jetbrains' IntelliJ parsed Java Editor, the CTRL+SHIFT+T key combination navigates to the Test Class of the current class by graceful conventions. I tried to improve the current questions by flipping through ArchUnit sources, I'll get back here if I found a quicker way than the suggested code.

Comment: When a class like `C` does override an interface method that has a default implementation like `I.c` then the coverage test can open the source of `TestC` methods and ensure that the test class `TestC` does call `C.c` and not `I.c`.

@18446744073709551615 can you explain what is the criteria that a coverage test can use to determine if `C` should override the default `I.c` method ?

Comment: @simonarame The coverage test cannot know if the default implementation `I.c()` is ok for `C`, but it can know if a test for `c()` is present (it must be present); and we assume that if a test for `c()` is present, it tells us whether the implementation of `c()` is correct. So if the test for `C.c()` fails, and C does not override `I.c()`, then  either `C` must override `I.c()`, or `I.c()` has a bug and must be fixed.